# Resize-reduce/thumbnail Images during uploading with ImageMagick

Tags: php, upload, imagick

i have html form to upload images , I want to Resize-reduce/thumbnail during the uploading process.

```
$uploadDir= "/uploads";
$imageName= $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tempPath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file ($tempPath,$uploadDir);
```

resize-reduce:

```
convert $imageName -resize 800x600 -strip -quality 50 -interlace line output.jpg
```

thumbnail:

```
convert $imageName -resize x120 -gravity center -crop 120x120+0+0 +repage thumb_output.jpg
```

this is the first time using Imagick !

thank you

Comment: i didn't !! this is my question 'I want to Resize-reduce/thumbnail during the uploading process.' ???

Comment: ok!! how can i Resize-reduce/thumbnail images with imagemagick?
Are you satisfied now!

Comment: Are you asking, how to invoke ImageMagick from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

run these commands using exec() in background using nohup.

```
exec('nohup convert ... > /dev/null &');
```