# how can i set imagemagick Path?

Tags: php, upload, imagemagick

asked my Hosting company what is the path of imagemagick ?

and they gave me this '/home2/artists5/php'

ok now how can i initiate or exec imagemagick commands on my script?

for example :

i have this form to upload images :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" /><p /><input type="submit" value="Uplaod" />
```

and this is upload.php:

```
$uploadDir= "uploads";

$imageName= $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$error    = $_FILES['fiel']['erroe'];

if ($error > 0 ) 
{
die("Error uploading file! Code $error");
}
else
{
if(move_uploaded_file ($tempPath,$uploadDir."/".$imageName))
   echo $imageName. " has been uploaded!";
}
```

i want to execute this command while uploaing the image:

```
convert $imageName -resize 800x600 -strip -quality 50 -interlace line output.jpg
```

what should I do ?

i have this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480331/resize-reduce-thumbnail-images-during-uploading-with-imagemagick) , but no one answer me ?

Comment: see exec php function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: No , i want to know how i use imagemagick ? thx

Comment: this question appears to have been asked elsewhere (Google??)   http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Frontend-to-ImageMagick/

Comment: my question is do i need to define the path of imagemagick on my script or not , if so .. how can i define it ? i'm not Expert

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the exec command?  Just include the path to convert in the parameter

eg instead of

```
exec(' convert ...
```

use

```
exec('/home2/artists5/php/convert ...
```